# Geting the most count by id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a forum. I want to perform an SQL query so I can get the user who has the most blog submissions. I have 2 tables, `blogs` and `users`.

The `blogs` table has `author_id` which is the `user_id` from the `users` table.

So here is what I tried to do but without success:

```
SELECT b.author_id FROM blogs b 
INNER JOIN users u ON b.author_id = u.user_id 
ORDER BY count(author_id) DESC 
GROUP BY b.author_id 
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Could you please help me to find the user with most blog submissions, or in other words, I need to find a `author_id` that has most occurrence in the `blogs` table. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, the syntax in your query is slightly wrong: GROUP BY should be before ORDER BY, like you can see in all the answers.

Comment: This is splitting hairs, I know... but is it a forum, or a blog? The two concepts are very different.

Comment: @Filmzy If you are asking about my site, its a forum. Instead of blog I may be should have used word "topic", but thats just a preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to join to `users` for this, you just need a GROUP BY and a LIMIT:

```
SELECT author_id
FROM blogs
GROUP BY author_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The GROUP BY tells the COUNT which groups it should count; in this case, it should collect up the blogs for each `author_id` and count those as a single group.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. We have 5000+ users, thats why I am telling that I am not 100% sure. But it looks to be correct :)

Comment: @Nazar: You can drop the `LIMIT` and use `SELECT author_id, COUNT(*)` to look at all the counts.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(a.*) AS total, a.author_id
FROM blogs AS a
GROUP BY author_id
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The different parts of your query are in the wrong order. This should work

```
SELECT b.author_id
FROM blogs b
INNER JOIN users u ON b.author_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY b.author_id
ORDER BY COUNT( b.author_id ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

See the MySQL documentation regarding the [`SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Also, I assume that your example is a bit simplified since there is, as others have noted, really no need for a join in this case.

Comment: Yea, mine is indeed simplified. I didn't know the correct way, hence tried to use joining tables. Thanks for advice!